# Webpack 5 - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, package

After the last Webpack upgrade, a couple of days ago, my projects get this error when trying to start them:

`(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname)`

`{ import path from 'path';`

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

and it's comming from my `webpack.config.babel.js` which has these lines at the top:

```
import path from 'path';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
```

I tried to change the extension to .mjs and I also tried to add `type: module` in package.json and it didn't help.

Comment: Any Luck with this?

Comment: @Nikasv unfortunately not yet.

Comment: This is driving me crazy. I thought the whole point of naming the config file "webpack.config.babel.js" was so that you could use imports. I'd never tried this until now, using webpack 5.10.1, so I have no previous experience of ever having gotten this to work at all.